# r output a variable with mismatch pattern

Tags: r

I have a list of text files with different names.

input:

```
peter_input.txt
paul_input.txt
mary_input.txt
john_input.txt
.
.
. 
kenneth_input.txt
martin_input.txt
marshall_input.txt
```

I would like to create a variable that only include the names.
Desired output:

```
diff_name

[1] "peter" "paul" "mary" "john"
[5] . . . "kenneth" "martin" 
[11] "marshall"
```

Can the package `dplyr` be of any help ?

Comment: thank you very much for the edit, it is easy to read now.

Comment: `sub("_input.txt", "", x)` is this what you need? where `x` is a list of all your file names

Comment: It dependes on how the files names are stored? As data frame, as list, all separate strings?